# Mac OS X 10.11.3 Key Chain Keychain Access can't export certs in .p12 format in remote terminal sessions

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm doing remote iOS development using Visual Studio 2015. My remote Mac is running OS 10.11.3 ("El Capitan"). When attempting to export a certificate in the login keychain to .p12 format, I'm constantly presented with a Keychain Access prompt to enter the password for the login keychain prior to the export; Keychain Access never accepts the password to export the cert. I know for sure that the keychain password is correct and I even reset the login keychain several times.

I'm using a remote session through VNC and also RDP (using iRAPP Server). This could be a problem accessing Keychain access in a remote session so I will try on the same Mac when I get physical access later today. 
  
 Has anyone else experienced this cert export failure in Keychain Access using a remote session?

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I will for future Apple questions.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with running Keychain Access in a remote (VNC or RDP) session. Certificate export with private keys (e.g. .p12) does not work remotely. I tried the same exact steps on the same Mac when I gained physical access and it exported the certificate with no issues.